# занимаемое место на винте

Tags: filesize, freebsd, perl

Как узнать размер который занимает файл на винчестере (желательно на perl)
функция stat возвращает размер самого файла ...

Что то мне подсказывает что нужно нормализировать размер исходя из текущей файловой системы, а именно от blockSize, но уверенности нету, может кто-то прояснить ?

OS: FreeBSD 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gaal@linux-lybs:~> du -B 1 Maple_13_InstallLog.log 
4096    Maple_13_InstallLog.log
gaal@linux-lybs:~> du -B 1 --apparent-size Maple_13_InstallLog.log 
2487    Maple_13_InstallLog.log
```

Верхнее - место занимаемое в ФС, нижнее - реальный размер файла.

Comment: c du это конечно хорошо, но вот вызывать du порядка 10 млн раз как то не очень хочется :(
Но спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Во-первых, du можно вызвать сразу для множества файлов.<p>
Во-вторых, уверен есть способ и через перл.

Answer (score 2):

[stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) :

```
11 blksize preferred block size for file system I/O
12 blocks actual number of blocks allocated
```

т.е. надо перемножить эти параметры, но у меня на OpenSuse blocks в 8 раз больше чем должно быть, если кто знает почему - с удовольствием выслушаю (файловая система ext4).

P.S. а на windows они вообще пустые

Comment: на ум приходит только одно: значение в битах, а не байтах

Comment: В extN выделенные блоки считаются по 512 байт (размер сектора). В 8 раз больше, когда размер блока в ФС 4096 (512 * 8). Так сделано из-за обратной совместимости.

Comment: Ещё в доках по stat() написано:
"The st_blocks field indicates the number of blocks allocated to the file, 512-byte units."
Но в extN это хранится на уровне ФС. Не знаю, как в остальных ФС.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так, если надо для большого количества файлов:

```
#unit_size нужно определить лишь один раз для корня дерева файлов
#при условии, что внутри нет примонтированных ФС
$unit_size = `stat --format="%B" $some_root_dir_of_fs_or_tree`;
chomp($unit_size);
$ondisk_size = (stat "qwerty")[12] * $unit_size;
```

Comment: Еще делить на 8 нужно